# Step Definition not found in Cucumber java

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, bdd

I have a small cucumber-JUnit example in Eclipse which I could run successfully. After that I renamed the Package name and played around with the code a bit. But now it complains that:-

```
Feature: Calculator
  I use Calculator instead of calculating myself

  @smokeTest
  Scenario Outline: Add two numbers # src/test/java/cucumber/junit/test/calculatorFeature.feature:17
    Given I have a calculator
    When I add 2 and 3
    Then the result should be 5

  @smokeTest
  Scenario Outline: Add two numbers # src/test/java/cucumber/junit/test/calculatorFeature.feature:18
    Given I have a calculator
    When I add 4 and 5
    Then the result should be 9

  @regressionTest
  Scenario: Subtract one number from another # src/test/java/cucumber/junit/test/calculatorFeature.feature:21
    Given I have a calculator
    When I subtract 2.5 from 7.5
    Then the result should be 5.0

3 Scenarios (3 undefined)
9 Steps (9 undefined)
0m0,000s


You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@Given("^I have a calculator$")
public void i_have_a_calculator() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^I add (\\d+) and (\\d+)$")
public void i_add_and(int arg1, int arg2) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^the result should be (\\d+)$")
public void the_result_should_be(int arg1) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^I subtract (\\d+)\\.(\\d+) from (\\d+)\\.(\\d+)$")
public void i_subtract_from(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^the result should be (\\d+)\\.(\\d+)$")
public void the_result_should_be(int arg1, int arg2) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

My Runner looks like:

```
package cucumber.junit.test;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(

        features = "src/test/java/cucumber/junit/test/calculatorFeature.feature",
        //This executes all the scenarios tagged as smokeTest and regressionTest
        format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"}, tags = {"@smokeTest,@regressionTest"},
        //This will execute all the scenarios except those tagged as smokeTest
        // tags = {"~@smokeTest"},
        //glue = {"src/test/java/cucumber/junit/maven/cucumber_jvm/maven"}     
        glue = {"src/test/java/cucumber/junit/test"}

    )
    public class RunCalculatorTest {    

    }
```

[image]

I have checked the path to the glue carefully and it is correct. I have also updated my project and done mvn clean install. Could someone please point out why is it not finding stepdefinition ?

Comment: Try changing `glue` option to this: `glue = {"cucumber.junit.test"}` or `glue = "cucumber.junit.test"`. I think it's looking for a package name.

Comment: exactly that was the issue. Thanks for the super quick answer. U can post it as answer then I will accept it as Answer. I am still wondering when it expects path and when package name. Because earlier it has worked successfully with path.

Comment: Should work with path aswell, could you try `glue = "src/test/java/cucumber.junit.test"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Glue* option is probably looking for a package name. Try this:

`glue = {"cucumber.junit.test"}`

or

`glue = "cucumber.junit.test"`

Check out this [post](http://blog.czeczotka.com/2014/07/22/cucumber-jvm-with-maven-in-minutes/), it's a bit old but should get you started in no time.

Comment: Just to let others know both of above suggestions work !